# Yubikey Private Key Generation & Storage 5 Series vs Bio Key

Tags: account-security, yubikey, u2f, fido

References:

1. Yubico’s Take on U2F Key Wrapping
   https://www.yubico.com/blog/yubicos-u2f-key-wrapping/
2. Key generation
   https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Key_generation.html
3. Discoverable Credentials / Resident Keys
   https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/Resident_Keys.html
4. FIDO 2 compared to FIDO U2F
   https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/FAQ.html

How are Yubico private keys (unique for each Relaying Party (RP)) generated and stored for a FIDO U2F credential session for the 5 Series Keys vs the Bio Keys.  Do they both use key wrapping of the private keys?  I’m pretty sure all the 5 Series Keys perform key wrapping for FIDO U2f (Reference 1/2).

I’ve been in contact with some other vendors of Bio Keys and they’ve indicated that the RP private key (FIDO U2F) is stored on the device and is not key wrapped for transmission to the RP.  This led me to wonder, if the Yubikey Bio stores the RP private key or key wraps for FIDO U2F?

From Ref 3/4, I know it is a different situation for FID02 Passwordless authentication.